# Error validating start date and end date

Tags: weblogic, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am using Jdeveloper 11.1.2.3.0. I want to have the End date on my form to be dependent on Start date. For this I copied the input value of the `StartDate` (`#{bindings.StartDate.inputValue}`) to the `MinValue` property of the `EndDate`. Both of the attributes are of type `Date` in database and of type `Timestamp` in VO. When I select a date in the `StartDate` calendar I am getting this error:

```
//C:/Oracle/Middleware/jdeveloper/jdev/system11.1.2.3.39.62.76.1/o.j2ee/drs/Contract
Management/ViewControllerWebApp.war/searchContracts.jsf @90,101 
minValue="#{bindings.SigningDate.inputValue}": java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
Cannot convert 2013-06-12 00:00:00.0 of type class oracle.jbo.domain.Timestamp to class java.util.Date

ADF_FACES-60097:For more information, please see the server's error log 
for an entry beginning with: ADF_FACES-60096:Server Exception during PPR, #2
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Are both enddate and start date the same data type?

Comment: Yes of course, sorry for being late, I thought that nobody had replied..

Comment: Have you tried instead having Start Date update End Date from the Model project? That seems to me the better place to do this. You can setup EndDate dependent on StartDate on your ViewOjbect - so whenever StartDate is updated, EndDate is updated to a minimum value. Also, you can have your respective business rules where End Date can't be less than Start Date, etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change datatype of both start and end date to Date in EO and VO and also in impl classes if you have,
then paste #{bindings.StartDate.inputValue} to min value of end date,
and set auto submit true for start date.
Hope it will work

Comment: Your answer and this post made things work for me :) http://adfpractice-fedor.blogspot.com/2013/11/validating-dates-with.html